# Lambda Expression - is it evaluating correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, custom-attributes

I have the following piece of code which doesn't seem to be acting right. There is a property which has one attribute which is not of type `FieldMapAttribute`, but still it goes into the if condition where I am checking the count matching that type of attribute.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo _property in _properties)
{
    var attributes = _property.GetCustomAttributes(false);
    if (attributes.Select(a => a.GetType() == typeof(FieldMapAttribute)).Count() > 0)
    {
        colname = (attributes.Select(a => a.GetType() == typeof(FieldMapAttribute)).Cast<FieldMapAttribute>().First()).DbColumnName;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to understand what is going on here?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming what you're trying to do is check whether a `FieldMapAttribute` attribute exists on the property, you should use

```
var attributes = _property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FieldMapAttribute), false);
if (attributes.Length > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Another option is to use

```
if (attributes.OfType<FieldMapAttribute>().Any())
```

You should note that the way you use `Select` is incorrect. [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891) is used to project elements into a new form. Your `Select` statement returns a list of `bools` - one for each attribute the property has (*any attribute*, not just of type `FieldMapAttribute`). This means that if your property looked like this

```
[SomeAttribute]
[SomeOtherAttribute]
[FieldMapAttribute]
public string MyProp { get; set; }
```

Then your select statement would yield the following result

```
false
false
true
```

As you can see, calling `Count` on this result set will always return the number of custom attributes set on the property (again, *any attribute*).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not my downvote, but PropertyInfo.IsDefined is a simpler approach for the test.

Comment: Both the answers are very helpful and I really appreciate Jon & Adi both. Thanks guys I seem to be running smoothly again.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of exactly what's going on in your current code, it looks to me like it could be written *much* more simply:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    if (property.IsDefined(typeof(FieldMapAttribute), false))
    {
        colName = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FieldMapAttribute), false)
                          .Cast<FieldMapAttribute>()
                          .First()
                          .DbColumnName;            
    }
}
```

(Note that that will end up with the *last* property defining the attribute as the one which specifies the column name. Is that what you want?)

Or even using LINQ for the whole thing:

```
var attrType = typeof(FieldMapAttribute);
var attr = properties.SelectMany(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(attrType), false)
                     .Cast<FieldMapAttribute>()
                     .FirstOrDefault();
if (attr != null)
{
    colName = attr.DbColumnName;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, but wouldn't this cause looking up the property's attributes twice instead of once in cases where `FieldMapAttribute` was defined?

Comment: @AdiLester: Potentially (although not in the second option). Unless I had any reason to think that was actually a bottleneck though, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks Jon...I appreciate your reply and help. :)

Comment: Jon I had to make small change in your suggestion to make it work. colname = (_property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FieldMapAttribute), false).Cast<FieldMapAttribute>().First()).DbColumnName;